# CSS Column-Count and Margins

Tags: javascript, css, html, stylesheet

Basically what I am trying to do is re-create the windows 8 style "horizontal" menus that stack like so-

1 | 5

2 | 6

3 | 7

4 | 8

and grow in the horizontal direction. So enter CSS3 Column-count! Works great, mostly.. The top first item in the second -> nth columns is just slighty higher than the first row. I have been messing with the CSS and I just can't get it right..

Here is a link to the jsbin-

http://jsbin.com/urubub/36/edit

Comment: Btw, this is experienced in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
margin-top: 0
```

to `.item` removes this inconsistency.

Comment: Got it! Thx. Had to change to individual set margins or margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;

Comment: @thebringking Btw, `margin: 0 10px 10px` is enough. The last values is then automatically set based on the second value.

Answer (score 0):

dont know too much about css3 rules, but adding this rule seemed to even things out:

```
ul > li:first-of-type{
    margin-top: 0;
}
```